Migrate AppIntent @Parameter values to a new @Parameter
I have a WidgetConfigurationIntent with the following parameters:
@Parameter(title: "Car", default: true)
var car: Bool

@Parameter(title: "Truck", default: false)
var truck: Bool

I want to replace these with a new parameter
@Parameter(title: "Vehicles", default: ["Car"])
var vehicles: [String]

If I do this, existing users who configured a widget will lose their settings, for example if they turned off Car and turned on Truck, upon installing this app update it will reset to the default of only Car since they've never configured this  @Parameter before.
I can keep the old parameters and use the parameterSummary to only show the new parameter in the widget, and I can access these values in the AppIntentTimelineProvider to display their old configuration, but how can I actually perform the migration to the new parameter so that I can no longer use the old parameters and eventually remove them? It seems I almost need a way to set that vehicles value programmatically to complete the transition from the old parameters to this new one.
